# How to make reCAPTCHA mandatory in jsf Form page

Tags: java, jsf, recaptcha

Iam new to JSF 
Coming to the point ,We are developing JSF form in which we are having some fields along with that we are having reCAPTCHA

We can make Input text as mandatory by using required="true" and  requiredMessage="#{}" but for  reCAPTCHA  unable to make it as mandatory because we are using in Div class as below.

...< Div class="g-recaptcha"   data-sitekey=" " style="margin-left:103%;">div

Answer (score 1):

I'd sugest you review the reCAPTCHA documention. 
https://www.google.com/recaptcha

reCAPTCHA is a javascript library and not part of the JSF framework so required="true" won't work.

This article outlines a basic integration of JSF form submission with a successful reCAPTCHA challenge:
https://www.journaldev.com/7133/how-to-integrate-google-recaptcha-in-java-web-application